# Copyright Symbol in CSS :after Pseudo-Element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

**SOLVED** - used `\00a9` instead of `&copy;`

Pretty self-explanatory:

```
body:after {
    content: "&copy; me";
    /* other formatting */
}
```

In HTML, the `&copy;` sequence inserts a copyright character. Can this be done in CSS Pseudo-Elements like I'm trying to do here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS:after encoding characters in content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030551/cssafter-encoding-characters-in-content)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

CSS doesn't use HTML's entities; it uses its own unicode escape sequences.

You need to use `\00a9` for the copyright symbol.

```
body:after {
  content:"\00a9 me";
}
```

See here for a cheat-sheet table which shows just about every entity/unicode string you'd ever need: http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/04/named-html-entities-in-numeric-order/

Comment: I just found my answer to a similar question which says the same thing. Now I feel really stupid to have answered this one differently. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030551/cssafter-encoding-characters-in-content/5030594#5030594

Comment: url is dead. Check here for the list: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/glyphs/

Comment: Cheat sheet provided didn't reference my symbols. This converter did the trick: https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/ paste code in top box, hit convert, and take the value under `css`.

Comment: The cheat sheet didn't even provide a standard exclamation mark! Might I suggest using the following link - https://unicode-table.com