# CSS Content displaying down arrow beside a span tag

Tags: html, css, encoding

Weird , i had this working before but stopped out now and doesn't seem to get corrected. I would like to display a down arrow through CSS using `Content` but the content does not get encoded(or what ever that process is known as).

#### JsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/HjuGR/1/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After looking up this issue, I think you can use a backslash followed by the unicode number in the content string value http://archivist.incutio.com/viewlist/css-discuss/60075. This worked for me

```
.drop::after{content:"\2193"}​
```

Comment: the Twitter Bootstrap guys seem to use it for down arrow in the menu. How does that work then

Answer (score 3):

You need to use UTF-encoded symbols here:

```
.drop::after{content:"\2193"}​
```

[Here similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030551/cssafter-encoding-characters-in-content)