# Property content doesn't display

Tags: css, spring-mvc

In my css i put:

```
nav label:AFTER {
   content: "  ▾";
}
```

But in chrome it display like this:

```
content: " â–¾";
```

i already add `<meta charset="utf-8"/>` in my jsp page and `@CHARSET "utf-8";` in css file.

Comment: Checkout this, better to use code of symbols.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030551/cssafter-encoding-characters-in-content

Comment: thanks but there is no other solution ?

Comment: to be honest, i don't know any other crossbrowser way to do this.

Comment: There should be no problem if your CSS file is UTF-8 encoded and the Content-Type response header's charset is UTF-8.

Comment: Where can i put the Content-Type response header's charset ? and how ?

Comment: i add `<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>` and it's work if i put `▾` in jsp page but not if i put `▾` in css file !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it's work just with

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
```

i try this code at work but it didn't work but when i went to home it's work with my pc !

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this:

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul{
list-style-type: none;
}

ul li{
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
margin-right: 10px;
}

ul li:after {
content:'';
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
right: -10px;
border-left: 3px solid transparent;
border-right: 3px solid transparent;    
border-top: 3px solid black;
}
```

And [the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c9ra2/)..

Comment: thanks it's work but i want a another and easy solution of charset.